# How to pattern match string expression in array_contains function in hive?

Tags: sql, arrays, string, hive

Consider a column A as an array of strings. Now I would like to search for all the rows in the table to have a string of a particular pattern. I know array_contains() function can be used to check for the exact matches, but is there a way to check for patterned matches.

```
select * from table 
where array_contains(A,"%123%");
```

Is it possible to do pattern matches like this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use:

```
select distinct t1.*
from table1 t1 lateral view
     explode(t1.A) tmp as arr
where arr like '%123%';
```

There is a way to eliminate the `select distinct`, but I'm not sure if Hive supports it:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from explode(t1.A) as arr
              where arr like '%123%'
             );
```

Or you can use this somewhat kludgy method:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where concat_ws('|', t1.A) like '%123%';
```

Answer (score 1):

First generate row number. Then explode your array column with [lateral view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView), then filter out rows that didn't match the pattern, e.g.,

```
with table1 as (
    select row_number() over () as rnum, *
    from your_table
),
table2 as (
    select *, arr
    from table1 lateral view explode(A) tmp as arr
    where arr like '%123%'
),
table3 as (
    select distinct rnum from table2
)
select *
  from table1 t1
  left semi
  join table3 t3
  on t1.rnum = t3.rnum
```